# How to persuade saved connections in SSMS projects to actually remember their password

Tags: sql-server, ssms, projects-and-solutions, password-storage

Is there any way to persuade saved connections in SSMS projects to remember their password?

There's a checkbox on the connection to "remember password" but when I open a query inside the project the saved password doesn't appear.

If I cancel the login and then run the query, the saved password miraculously appears...

Is there any way of getting the saved password to populate when opening a query?

Comment: It's always worked for me. Perhaps you have a corrupted `UserSettings.ml` file somewhere inside `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio`?

Comment: UserSettings.xml looks fine. Additionally, when I run a query in the project, the password is remembered - it's just when opening the query it doesn't remember the password. I'll update the question.